# Piecewise functions on Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, piecewise

What is efficient (speed) way to apply Piecewise functions on Numpy Array?

Say, for example, Piecewise functions are like

```
For (1) :  x<=2 f(x) = 2*x + x^2
    (2) :  x>2  f(x) = -(x^2 + 2)
```

Here's what I did.

```
data = np.random.random_integers(5, size=(5,6))
print data
np.piecewise(data, [data <= 2, data > 2],
             [lambda x: 2*x + pow(2, x),
              lambda x: -(pow(x, 2) + 2)])

data = 
[[4 2 1 1 5 3]
 [4 3 3 5 4 5]
 [3 2 4 2 5 3]
 [2 5 4 3 1 4]
 [5 3 3 5 5 5]]
output = 
array([[-18,   8,   4,   4, -27, -11],
       [-18, -11, -11, -27, -18, -27],
       [-11,   8, -18,   8, -27, -11],
       [  8, -27, -18, -11,   4, -18],
       [-27, -11, -11, -27, -27, -27]])
```

Is there an efficient method to go by for smaller arrays, large arrays, many functions etc? My concern is with lambda functions being used. Not sure if these are Numpy optimized.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you should not be concerned about the lambdas: Numpy optimisation is about reducing call overhead, by letting functions evaluate many values at the same time in batch. In each call to `np.piecewise`, each function in `funclist` (the function parts) is called exactly once, with a numpy array consisting of all values where the appropriate condition is true. Thus, these lambda's are called in a numpy-optimised way.

Similar is `np.select` (and `np.where` for exactly two parts). The call overhead is the same as it is vectorised the same way, but it will evaluate all functions for all data-points. Thus, it will be slower than `np.piecewise`, particularly, when the functions are expensive. In some cases, is is more convenient (no lambda), and one can more easily extend the concept to many variables.

Comment: Good answer.  One other advantage of using `np.select()` or `np.where()` is that then you have access to the entire array when doing the calculations.  If your function depends on other values in the input (for example, neighboring values of each point), this will be useful.  But in the OP's case it doesn't matter, and `np.piecewise()` is good.